# Caching with AngularJS CacheFactory and socket.io

Tags: angularjs, socket.io, cachefactory

For our application, to improve the performance, we are at a point where we are thinking about caching the data that is being fetched from the server and to use some sort of a caching invalidation mechanism.

The data that gets updated directly on the server side, which is not initiated from the client is quite minimal. So I am just wondering if refreshing the cache by using some invalidation mechanism is really warranted. I am thinking of avoiding the additional calls that we would incur after the cache invalidates, even when the data in the backend hasn't changed.

So naturally, I am thinking of building some sort of a framework to get socket.io and the angular cachefactory to work together so that the cache gets updated real time, which will eliminate a lot of unnecessary traffic that would hit the server.

Surprisingly, I could not find a lot of information around this sort of a framework. So makes me wonder if there are any problems that might be lurking in the background.

It would be nice to get the opinion of people who have used these frameworks to see if this is a workable and more importantly a reliable solution for a web (SPA) application.

Thanks in advance!